# convert (.sqlite) map to RMaps

Tags: openstreetmap, sqlite, mobile-atlas-creator, osmdroid

how to convert a map (.sqlite) to RMaps by MOBAC or other app?

- THE MAP TYPE : OSMDroid
- MAP FILE NAME : NEW.sqlite
- MAP ATTACHMENT FILES : NEW.sqlite-journal

I don't have more experience about this 
so please i need easiest way to do this with simple explanation

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, FYI sqlite is not a map but rather a database

Comment: i know that database
but this database contains map imagery
like RMaps DB or MBtiles.

Comment: any help please ?